# Ubuntu 12.04 mouse wheel not working

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mousewheel

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed as a dual boot.  I recently changed my mouse and with the new mouse the scroll wheel has stopped working.

The 'new' mouse is actually an older version 'borrowed' mouse.

It seems to be a fairly basic one.

Anyone got any thoughts on why it shouldn't work?

Thx in advance.

Comment: try updating the system using sudo apt-get update and restarting the machine. Is this a branded mouse ?

Comment: @hYk the system is up to date.  No its not a 'well known' brand.  Something from Xtreme Technologies. I've also tried the mouse on a windows system and the wheel does work so it's something to do with the signal not being recognised by Ubuntu.